# select count first or data for checking for auto increment id

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am checking when a row is added using auto incrementing id 
(simple query example SELECT id FROM tbl where id > 1) but wondering which method is better

1) have 2 queries a count(id) where id > lastid and then select if count > 0 
2) have 1 query -  just select ... and let it return 0 results/do nothing if there are no new rows 

My understanding is the count method would be better as it does not touch the actual data and uses a index count, but uses 2 queries but the 1 query would have more impact and try to fetch from disk each time

This is for Mysql and a INNODB table

Comment: Welcome to SO, Chris. Are you aware of the `AUTO_INCREMENT` Flag for a colum? What do you want to to with your "check"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `PRIMARY KEY` column with a `AUTO_INCREMENT` flag. So you dont have to update the id manually:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
  `ID` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO myTable (name) VALUES ("Tom");
INSERT INTO myTable (name) VALUES ("Jerry");

SELECT * FROM myTable;
```

If you want to select the last used `ID` in this case you can do a

```
select LAST_INSERT_ID() ;
```